# Android alarm launching new activity and resetting the alarm

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, multiple-instances

I have been searching for this since morning and referred to most of the android alarm problems on stackoverflow.

I am trying to set multiple alarms with different intents. On receiving the the alarm, I want the alarm to be cancelled and the activity to come in front, in case its already running, or start again if it was killed, but this time the alarm shouldnt be set again. I dont want the other alarms to be effected. 
Currently, the problem is that clicking on the notification starts the activity again and resets the alarm. If I try to cancel it using alarmmanager.cancel, it doesnt notify the user at all.
Here is my code, please help

My MainActivity thats sets multiple alarms

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();       //for using this you need to import java.util.Calendar;

    // add minutes to the calendar object
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.MONDAY);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 8);
//  cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    AlarmManager mgrAlarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
       intent.putExtra("title", "notification no."+String.valueOf(i));
       intent.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID", String.valueOf(i));
       // Loop counter `i` is used as a `requestCode`
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, i, intent, 0);
       // Single alarms in 1, 2, ..., 10 minutes (in `i` minutes)
       mgrAlarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000 * i, 
                    pendingIntent); 

       intentArray.add(pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

My AlarmReceiver Class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager manger = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Alarm App", System.currentTimeMillis());

            Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
            String title=extras.getString("title");
            int notif_id=Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("NOTIFICATION_ID"));

    //here we get the title and description of our Notification
                Class myclass = MainActivity.class;
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notif_id, 
                    new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);
            String note=extras.getString("note");
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, note, title, contentIntent);
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    //here we set the default sound for our 
    //notification   
            // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
            manger.notify(notif_id, notification);
}

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MainActivity, you can differentiate a launch from the Notification with an additional parameter in the intent.  You would anyway need the notification id to cancel the particular notification.  So, you can try the following in your MainActivity

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent appIntent = this.getIntent();
        int notif_id = appIntent.getIntExtra( "my_notification_id", -1 ) ;
        if( notif_id != -1 )
        {
            Log.d ( "LOG_TAG",  "Launched from Notification ");
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(     NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
            nm.cancel( notif_id );

           /* Do the separate processing here */
           .....
        }
        else
        {
            /* Your previous onCreate code goes here */
```

In the file AlarmReceiver.java, you need to make the following changes

```
//PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notif_id, new           Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

Intent appIntent = new Intent(  context, MainActivity.class );
appIntent.putExtra( "my_notification_id", notif_id );
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notif_id, appIntent, 0);
```

Hope this helps.